# Cannot convert value of type 'UnsafePointer<T>' to expected argument type 'UnsafePointer<Int16>'

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, swift5, unsafemutablepointer

I am trying to manually convert Swift 3 code to Swift 5, but am getting error when trying to cast memory.

```
   let buffer: UnsafePointer<Int16>

   init<T>(buffer: UnsafePointer<T>) {
      self.buffer  = UnsafePointer<Int16>(buffer)
   }
```

The error is forced typecast which new Swift version is not allowing.

```
   Cannot convert value of type 'UnsafePointer<T>' to expected argument type 'UnsafePointer<Int16>'
```

I am not sure what is the right way to rebind memory to '`UnsafePointer<Int16>`', *forcibly*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The `UnsafePointer` reference page](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/unsafepointer) explains the correct, but tedious, procedure:

> When you need to permanently rebind memory to a different type, first obtain a raw pointer to the memory and then call the `bindMemory(to:capacity:)` method on the raw pointer. The following example binds the memory referenced by `uint8Pointer` to one instance of the `UInt64` type:
>
> ```swift
> let uint64Pointer = UnsafeRawPointer(uint8Pointer)
>                           .bindMemory(to: UInt64.self, capacity: 1)
> ```

You're supposed to tell the compiler how much memory you're rebinding (using the `capacity` parameter) because it may have already copied some of that memory to registers or the stack and it needs to know you're invalidating those copies.

Comment: I modified the line as self.buffer = UnsafeRawPointer(buffer).bindMemory(to: T.self, capacity: length)....but still get the same error

Comment: It should be `.bindMemory(to: UInt16.self, capacity: someNumberOfUInt16s)` because you want to create an `UnsafePointer<UInt16>`.